# What should be a role of a QA person who is doing Pair Testing with a Developer before code commit?

Tags: agile-testing, agile

In my previous company we had a practice of doing smoke testing for 10 minutes before code commit by the developer. A QA need to sit with the associate developer and need to perform a quick smoke test(for details, you may see my blog post http://shantonusarker.blogspot.com/2012/09/pre-qa-essential-step-in-agilekan.html). 
We are used to follow KAN BAN(customized).

- What should be QA mind set while testing this?
- What are the things need to take care about?
- How they will interact on bug found or not found?
- How can the QA person keep tracking the side issues that arise while working on the assigned task?
- How to make a report to QA team on the test action that he just performed?

We had a practice, but I just want to know if there is more interesting ideas.

Comment: Given the low tester/dev ration and large number of commits per day I would say that either informal interaction with dev is preferred (as in pair programming or informal code reviews) or if you want to track the problems, then reviews should be less torough or not for every commit.

Comment: Why QA needs to track those issues? To me this looks reviewing and extending unit tests, the same way as in pair programming, only the peer doing a review is QA. And when a peer finds and issue it just tells dev to correct it or correct it herself.

Comment: Just to understand the practice better. Have your devs practiced pair programming? Did you have code reviews in any form (Peer reviews or more formal)? What was the benefit of QA pre-testing over those practices? What things QA found that devs overlooked?

Comment: And one more. How large where those commits? Did QA performed black box testing in the practice you describe, or he was rather supposed to know the code well and do unit testing?

Comment: @dzieciou- Devs are doing pair programming in regular basis. Code review used to be done by separate pair with at least one senior level dev. The benefit is 1. In our large team we get a lot of discussions for implanting the actual requirements, way to solve the problem more easy and logical way. And, yes QA used to find the things that the dev overlooked or even get the logical errors also. Additional to that, qa make a list of dependent features need to tested.

Comment: @dzieciou :  QA are involved with this for both Unit tests and functional implementations(if it does not have unit test). And, comments depend on the complexity of the feature. some time 2 lines, some time 2 pages. QA performs Black box testing after completion(commit and build) of a ticket and before release only. Most of the time qa knows about the code module wise and suggest unit test cases(written in nunit or even normal english)

Comment: Shantonu, I see questions in this post, but I am having trouble determining what your business problem you want solved is. Could you clarify what your end-objective is?

Comment: @corsiKa- I wanted to verify , either any other are doing the same thing or not?. if they are doing, are we correct from their prospective? If some one have some additional ideas regarding this king of interaction in the software development process. We evolve this process from the culture of the dev & qa group. Let's other people have some comments  on what we are doing. That's all.

Comment: @Shantonu Sorry for not getting back to this sooner. This isn't currently a good fit for the format. Questions should revolve around an actual business problem (i.e. a specific deficiency in the process). This is more of a discussion than a question. If you can refine it into specific problems that you feel need expert attention, we can un-hold it.

Comment: @corsiKa- yes, it is not actually a question, it might be a discussion. Thanks